# Labelling Issue Red Matrix around Label

Tags: qgis, labeling, printing, print-composer

I use QGIS 2.12 64-Bit Version on Win7.
I have a problem with red matrix wich show up around every label. I want to delete them or make them invisible. It looks like in the following screenshot[image]

Does somebody know how to solve this?
[image]

Comment: Does this occur in the composer or in the main canvas in QGIS?

Comment: Both, composer and map canvas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the setting for "Show label candidates" enabled. On the labeling tab for your layer properties, click the "Automated placement settings" button:

[image]

Then, uncheck "Show candidates":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be a new feature made available in QGIS 2.12 according to the Changelog:

- [Option for obstacle-only layers](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog212/#feature-option-for-obstacle-only-layers)

The following is quoted from the website along with the images:

> In the screenshot you can see that the Streets have the option “Discourage other labels from covering features in this layer” enabled. **The red labels derived from polygon geometries are thus placed to avoid intersection with the street axis**. You have to enable “Horizontal” or “Free” on the polygon layer in order to achieve proper results.

[image: Image taken from website, link provided above]

Therefore, try disabling the "Discourage other lavels from covering features in this layer" option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems that this option belongs to the red matrix, i didn't had that Option "Discourage other labels from covering features in this layer" enabled. So, when i chose this option the red marks disappear but also the labelling.

Comment: When you're showing all labels, in the _Rendering_ tab there's an **Obstacles** option, try enabling/disabling this. I am just guessing because I haven't come across this issue, hopefully others can also advise :)

Comment: i currently tried to set a rule to define labels, so far without any obvious reason after i setted a rule but with same label settings as before the red matrix are now black.